# Can't import numpy

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to import numpy on Python, it says:

> ImportError: No module named numpy

If I try to install numpy, it says it has already been installed. It seems like it's been installed, but in a wrong place? I don't know where it should be though.

Python version is 2.4.6, but if I try to install a newer version, like 2.7, it says it has already been installed.

Comment: If you're not on an OS that depends on Python, i.e. you're on Mac or Windows, try uninstalling your python and then reinstalling it.

Comment: @AaronHall (a bit off topic) Mac and Windows depend on python? I had no idea. Do you have a link to a related article or something?

Comment: @Dunno Did I clarify myself properly?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask Python if numpy is installed, by searching through `sys.path`:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...  if os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, 'numpy')):
...   print p
...   break
... else:
...  print "Numpy not found"
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

In this case, I have numpy installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. "Numpy not found" will be printed if it's not installed.

If you're on Windows (sounds like maybe?) then you need to make sure that the path is set up correctly. It sounds like you may have more than one python installed, and numpy is being installed in one of them, but your default interpreter is the other one.