# error importing numpy in python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy, import, homebrew

I tried installing numpy with homebrew, but instead it installed in the Python 2.7 version. I found this out by following the answer on this post: [Can't import numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543745/cant-import-numpy)

Which is very strange especially since I specifically asked for python3:

```
M$ brew install numpy --with-python3
Warning: homebrew/python/numpy-1.11.1 already installed
```

However, when I try importing it in Python 3.5 I always get the same error:

```
  File "Dataframe.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

How can I get it to work as intended? I am on mac os 10.11.3

Comment: Why are you using homebrew to install `numpy`, a Python package?

Comment: I was using option 1 from the top answer to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615005/how-to-install-numpy-for-python-3-3-5-on-mac-osx-10-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have Python 3.5 installed by running `which python3` and `which python` (to make sure your versions aren't mixed up).

Then, to install for Python 3, you should run `pip3 install numpy`. It's a good idea to use the given Python tools to install Python-related packages.